# Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I have Example.xlsx spreadsheet with multiple pages:

[image]

The goal is to loop through daraframe `StateID` column and match with excel sheet name, and if it matches write into cell `B14` value `premiumtest`

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'\\username\Python\Treaty Year Report\Example.xlsx')
ws = [sheet.title for sheet in wb.worksheets]
print(ws)


for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if any(x in 'MTHLY-'+ row['StateID'] for x in ws): 
        ws['B14'] = row[2]
```

But I got an error:

```
  File "x:\Documents\Treaty Year Report\TreatyYearReport3", line 76, in <module>
    ws['B14'] = row[2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So why I cannot pass cell in worksheet? And if passing index, how can I specify particular cell?

Comment: `row['StateID']` or `row.iloc[2]`?

Comment: `ws` is a list and does not have keys. You might be looking for a dict comprehension instead?

Comment: Can I convert it to string?